# How to strip signature image while parsing the email body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I am only capturing all valid email addresses from email body using below method.

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> ParseAllEmailAddressess(string data)
    {
        HashSet<String> emailAddressess = new HashSet<string>();
        Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);
        foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
        {
            emailAddressess.Add(emailMatch.Value);
        }
        return emailAddressess;
    }
```

The problem here is outlook converts the Signature image into some random email address something like (image001.png@01D36870.C9EE4D60) . And my method considering it as valid email address and captures it. I want to strip off such email address while parsing email body.

I can think of splitting the email address with . before @ site and use the first index to match the image extension ".png" to identify valid email or not. But i think it not very efficient. Applying some reg ex to strip signature images content would be fast.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up creating below method to strip the signature images email address from the email body.

```
  public static readonly string[] _validExtensions = { "jpg", "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpeg","tiff","raw","psd" };

    public static bool IsImageExtension(string email)
    {
        bool isContainsImageExt = false;           

            MailAddress addr = new MailAddress(email);
            string username = addr.User;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && username.Contains('.'))
            {
                String[] parts = username.Split(new[] { '.' });
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parts[0]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parts[1]))
                {
                    if(_validExtensions.Contains(parts[1].ToLower()) && (parts[0].ToLower().Contains("image")))
                    {
                         isContainsImageExt = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        return isContainsImageExt;
    }
```